# Anime series from 1980s or 1990s about princess, protagonist and his robot who are flying to the Earth for help

Tags: story-identification, robots, space, anime

This anime series is about a protagonist whose planet was destroyed/conquered by an Evil empire and princess, along with the protagonist and courtiers, are flying to the Earth for help. They are pursued by a  general in black uniform  and his giant red robots in white helmets.The protagonist has a Grendizer-like robot and fights with the pursuers during the halts on different planets.  Also evil general likes to drink wine and he is human (not alien)  who works on Evil empire. The evil emperor and his courtiers and other generals are humanoids

Comment: Could it be Starzinger?